# How can I type that a function takes any function as an argument?

Tags: typescript

I have a higher-order function that wraps a function with an online check that I'm trying to write a type signature for, but I can't figure it out. This is what I've got so far:

```
const preventOffline = <T extends Function>(fn: T): T =>
  function() {  // Error: Type '() => any' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    if (!window.navigator.onLine) {
      alert("Sorry, please retry when you're online.");
      return undefined;
    }
    return fn.apply(this, arguments);
  };
```

I've also tried this, which for some reason gives me an error saying `T` is declared but never used.

```
export const preventOfflineHOF = <T, U>(fn: (T) => U): ((T) => U | undefined) =>
```

How can I annotate this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature says that the same type of function that was passed in should be returned but the compiler has no way of asserting that this is the case.

If you'd have a specific function signature that you were expecting then you could have done this for example:

```
const preventOffline = (fn: (p1: string, p2: number) => boolean): (p1: string, p2: number) => boolean => 
    function (p1: string, p2: number) {
        return false;
}
```

And the compiler won't complain.
But because you want to allow all functions, you'll just need to tell the compiler that you know what you are doing by casting to `any`:

```
const preventOffline = <T extends Function>(fn: T): T =>
    function () {
        if (!window.navigator.onLine) {
            alert("Sorry, please retry when you're online.");
            return undefined;
        }
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
} as any;
```

Another option is to remove the generics and accept just a `Function`:

```
const preventOffline = (fn: Function): Function =>
    ...
};
```

But then you lose the type of the passed in function and `preventOffline` will be just a `Function`.

Answer (score -2):

```
const preventOffline = <T extends Function>(fn: () => T): T =>
  function() {
    if (!window.navigator.onLine) {
      alert("Sorry, please retry when you're online.");
      return undefined;
    }
    return fn.apply(this, arguments);
 };
```

Comment: Probably because the type signature doesn't match up with what the function does. `T` is not the return value of the function passed in, but the type of the function passed in.

Comment: Also, seems like your code produces the same exact error: "Type '() => any' is not assignable to type 'T'". Have you even checked your code before you posted it as an answer?

Comment: I see, I misunderstood that fn is a function that should return `T`.